# AttributeError: module 'boto' has no attribute 'plugin'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, word2vec

I'm running a VM on Google Cloud Platform using Jupyter notebook with word2vec models. I have the following code snippet:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
amazon_word2vec = Word2Vec(model, min_count=1, size=100)
```

And it results in the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'boto' has no attribute 'plugin'
```

What is the solution to the above problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pip install google-compute-engine
```

install google compute engine and restart your vm and it works fine.