# Python3: AttributeError: module 'boto' has no attribute 'plugin'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, boto, gensim

I am running some code on a Google Platform Compute Engine VM and I get an error when I imported `Python boto` library.

The first time if I run 'import boto', the error message would be:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

Then I ran it again, a different error message came out:

> AttributeError: module 'boto' has no attribute 'plugin'

I tried installing **google-compute-engine** but it didn't work. I also tried different versions of **boto** but failed as well.

Answer (score 1):

As it is suggested by **user10360186** in [AttributeError: module 'boto' has no attribute 'plugin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414249/attributeerror-module-boto-has-no-attribute-plugin/52417342) answer. You have to execute

```
$ pip install google-compute-engine
```

and restart the VM.

Comment: Can you please confirm that running the same code twice without making any changes will give you different errors?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Not sure why but when you try to use boto on a google platform engine. There will be a file /usr/share/google/boto/boto_plugins/compute_auth.py, you need to modify the line from 'import urllib2' to 'import urllib.request as urllib2' to fit Python3. Then it is all good.