# gcloud version 306.0.0 causing "No module named 'urllib2'" errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

After updating `gcloud` from version 290.0.1 to version 306.0.0, I'm getting an error when I run a `gsutil cp` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 122, in RunMain
    import gslib.__main__
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 53, in <module>
    import boto
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/__init__.py", line 1216, in <module>
    boto.plugin.load_plugins(config)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/plugin.py", line 93, in load_plugins
    _import_module(file)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/plugin.py", line 75, in _import_module
    return imp.load_module(name, file, filename, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "/usr/share/google/boto/boto_plugins/compute_auth.py", line 18, in <module>
    import urllib2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

Following the downgrade instructions at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get#downgrading_cloud_sdk_versions temporarily fixes the issue:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=290.0.1-0
```

But I'd like to know how to get this working with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the version `306.0.0` and I ran a `gcloud cp` command, but I didn't face the issue. For this reason, checking for causes for the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'`, it seems that they are always related to a Python library that isn't working correctly - as you can check in this two examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794540/no-module-named-urllib2-how-do-i-use-it-in-python-so-i-can-make-a-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842387/no-module-named-urllib2).

However, in further searches, this plugin usually is used within Compute Engine and startup scripts to VMs with Python, more specific relating to the file `compute_auth.py` - which in the message seems to be related to the error - and as you can check for more information [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/+/290607ea0446d77a2f3d08c0229362695a4546c7/google-startup-scripts) about this file.

Considering that, the new version of Cloud SDK bring some [updates](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#compute_engine) to Compute Engine that could be causing the error. In case you are indeed, using Python within your applications, I would give it a try the solution from this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56961877/), that would be to update the file `compute_auth.py`, changing the line `import urllib2` to`import urllib.request as urllib2`.

In case this doesn't fix, raising a bug within [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0) will be the best option, for a further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. In my case, Travis CI/CD was giving the below error. What I did is add the below script to my `.travis.yml` file `before_script` section.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
635  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 21, in <module>
636    gsutil.RunMain()
637  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 121, in RunMain
638    import gslib.__main__
639  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 83, in <module>
640    import httplib2
641ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib2'
642error Command failed with exit code 1
```

Fix:

```bash
before_script:
   - pip install httplib2 crcmod
```